# How is my https:443 server serving http:80 also?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, https

I have a server EC2 instance running in AWS, behind a load balancer which currently doesn’t really do anything since I only have one instance (eventually, I planned on using it to scale and distribute traffic among multiple instances). I’m using Rt53 to point my domain name to the load balancer.

The webserver on the instance uses node(js) and express to serve the site over port 443 (https) with the proper certificates loaded in for encryption/identity/etc, generated by certbot using Let’s Encrypt.

The load balancer is configured like so:

[image: elb_config_1]
`load balancer general config`

[image: elb_config_2]
`load balancer target config`

So for both ports the load balancer points to the same server, using HTTPS:443, which I figured would force all connections to be encrypted. However, when I type in my URL as `http://mydomain.tld` it takes me to the webserver with no indication that it’s an https connection.

How is this happening? My nodejs server’s not set up to do anything over port 80, and I thought the load balancer should route all connections to port 443.

Comment: use redirect from http 8- to http 443 app.use(function(request, response){
  if(!request.secure){
    response.redirect("https://" + request.headers.host + request.url);
  }
});

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So if traffic is being forwarded to the same target group that means the same server port will be used for forwarded traffic from the load balancer (ALB).

Requests get mapped to this from the listener and translated to the port mapping for the target group instead.

Therefore, there are two possible practical scenarios that result from this configuration:

1. `client--[HTTP:80]-->ALB--[HTTPS:443]-->EC2`
2. `client--[HTTPS:443]-->ALB--[HTTPS:443]-->EC2`

Comment: You mean that if a client connects with HTTP using my current config then the external traffic to the load balancer (client-balancer) is plaintext, but the internal traffic (balancer-ec2) is encrypted?

Comment: So whatever the target groups port is and protocol, it'll send it via that. So yes you may have HTTP plaintext hitting the ALB. Then this forwards to the target instance as HTTPS

Comment: That’s interesting. I didn’t realize the ALB would be a way to support both protocols without having to support both on my server. I guess forcing an HTTPS connection will be as easy as setting `window.location.href` to “https://mydomain.tld” in the webserver, and the ALB handles the the initial HTTP connection before the switch.

Comment: Yes, or you can have the alb do the redirect instead: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Comment: different question related to the same project: I have a sessions implementation where the client has a session id cookie that corresponds to a session file on the webserver (not in a remote db). If I create additional instances behind the same ALB, might that mess up the client-server sessions sync? Can a client connection be switched to a different instance while doing actions on a page, or while switching pages?

Comment: Every web server has both bindings  80 and 443 but you have to do application or webserver level coding to redirect http 80 requests to  http 443

Answer (score 0):

If you disable 80 port and somebody type http://abc it will show error the best way is to redirect 80 requests to 443 
create a redirection  from 80 to 443.

```
app.use(function(request, response){
  if(!request.secure){
    response.redirect("https://" + request.headers.host + request.url);
  }
});
```

Generally most web server has multiple binding 80 and 443 both.Since if certificate expires you can use 80.
There are several methods of enabling an Apache redirect http to https:

Enable the redirect in the Virtual Host file for the necessary domain.

Enable it in the . htaccess file (previously created in the web root folder).

Use the mod_rewrite rule in the Virtual Host file.

Use it in the . htaccess file to force HTTPS.

https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/node-js/tutorials/make-https-the-defacto-standard/

Answer (score 0):

80 is the default port for the World Wide web. If you type in google.com:80, it will send you to google normally, while if you try google.com:81, you will not connect.